# Opening Vue component in Knockout js view model

Tags: vue.js, knockout.js, vue-component

So at my work we have decided to move to Vue. Previously we have been using Knockout js and a variety of other libraries to get an SPA going. Now considering that we have decide no new development will be in Knockout.

I am running into a problem where there is a page that is in Knockout JS and we need to add a button to it that ideally should open a Vue modal. We do have individual Vue.js pages working in the app so vue itself is all setup.

Could anyone here guide me if this is even possible to do?